# How to configure an UncaughtExceptionHandler in Spring Kafka Stream

Tags: java, spring-batch, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am using `spring-kafka` to implement a stream application using Spring Boot 1.5.16. The version of `spring-kafka` we are using is the 1.3.8.RELEASE.

I am searching for a method to close the boot application in case of an error that terminates all the threads associated withKafka Streams. I found that inside the [`KafkaStreams`](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html) there is the possibility to register a handle for uncaught exceptions. The method is [`setGlobalStateRestoreListener`](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-).

I saw that this method is exposed inside `spring-kafka` in the type `KStreamBuilderFactoryBean`.

My question is the following. Is there a simple way to register the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` as a bean and let Spring to properly inject inside the factory bean? Or should I create the `KStreamBuilderFactoryBean` my own and set manually the handler?

```
@Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_KSTREAM_BUILDER_BEAN_NAME)
public KStreamBuilderFactoryBean kStreamBuilderFactoryBean(StreamsConfig streamsConfig) {
    final KStreamBuilderFactoryBean streamBuilderFactoryBean = new KStreamBuilderFactoryBean(
            streamsConfig);
    streamBuilderFactoryBean.setUncaughtExceptionHandler((threadInError, exception) -> {
        // Something happens here
    });
    return streamBuilderFactoryBean;
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. In that old version you have to specify a `KStreamBuilderFactoryBean` bean by yourself with an appropriate injections and exactly that `KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_KSTREAM_BUILDER_BEAN_NAME`.

In the later versions we have already a `StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanConfigurer` to still keep that auto-configured `KStreamBuilderFactoryBean`, but be able to modify it whatever way we need.

**UPDATE**

You just create it as a bean in your application context and the framework will pick it up to apply on the `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean`:

```
    @Bean
    StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanConfigurer streamsCustomizer() {
        return new StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanConfigurer() {

            @Override
            public void configure(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean factoryBean) {
                factoryBean.setCloseTimeout(...);
            }

            @Override
            public int getOrder() {
                return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }

        };
    }
```

Comment: We are migrating to Spring Boot 2.2.6 from the version 1.5.15. Now, we understand the power of the solution that uses the interface `StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer`. Thanks for the reference!

Comment: Could you please provide a short example of how to use `StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer`? thank you

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I am using spring cloud stream kafka with functional Programing. I tried to do this as the way you suggested above. I did set StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler to the factoryBean expecting it will take care of all uncaught exceptions thrown by my service. But it didn't work. Do you know any working example to it with Functional programming. 
spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams: 3.2.1
spring-cloud-stream: 3.2.1
Spring-boot: 2.6.3

Comment: I would suggest you to raise a new SO question with more details .

Comment: @ArtemBilan this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71303705/spring-cloud-kafka-stream-streamsuncaughtexceptionhandler