# Spring cloud Kafka Stream StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to add StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler to my Kafka stream processor. This processor is written with Kafka functions. I had a look at the [suggestion provided by Artem Bilan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59791951/936329) to include the StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler to my service, but my exceptions never get caught/handled by it.

**Config Bean:**

```
@Autowired
UnCaughtExceptionHandler exceptionHandler;

@Bean
public StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanConfigurer streamsCustomizer() {
    return new StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanConfigurer() {

        @Override
        public void configure(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean factoryBean) {;
            factoryBean.setStreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler(exceptionHandler);
        }

        @Override
        public int getOrder() {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

    };
}
```

**Customized exception handler:**

```
    @Component
public class UnCaughtExceptionHandler implements StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler {

  @Autowired
  private StreamBridge streamBridge;

  @Override
  public StreamThreadExceptionResponse handle(Throwable exception) {
    return StreamThreadExceptionResponse.REPLACE_THREAD;
  }
}
```

**Stream Process function:**

```
@Autowired
private MyService service;

@Bean
public Function<KStream<String, Input>, KStream<String, Output>> processor() {
    final AtomicReference<KeyValue<String, Output>> result = new AtomicReference<>(null);
    return kStream -> kStream
            .filter((key, value) -> value != null)
            .filter((key, value) -> {
                Optional<Output> outputResult = service.process(value);
                if (outputResult.isPresent()) {
                    result.set(new KeyValue<>(key, outputResult.get()));
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            })
        .map((messageKey, messageValue) -> result.get());
}
```

I expect UnCaughtExceptionHandler to handle any exceptions thrown by the service.process() method. But exceptions never get into the handle method; instead, they propagate to the root and die the client. Had a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68930353/936329) as well, but I want to handle it more independent way.

Question: How do I handle any processing exceptions using [StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/kafka-streams/error-handling/)?

- Spring boot version: 2.6.3
- spring-cloud-stream version: 3.2.1
- spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams: 3.2.1
- kafka-streams: 3.0.0

Reproducible example: [spring-cloud-kafka-streams-exception](https://github.com/samhalpa/spring-cloud-kafka-streams-exception)

Comment: Simply use the customizer like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77596156/how-to-set-replace-thread-instead-of-shutdown-client-in-streamsuncaughtexception

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of things that you can try.

1. Try to set a breakpoint at [this line](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/main/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/config/StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.java#L327) in `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean` and see what the value of the configure is. That should give some clues.
2. I noticed that you set `Integer.MAX_VALUE` for the order in your configured impl. By default, `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean` uses a phase value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1000`, so there might be a chance that by the time the factory bean is ready to start, the configurer may not be available yet since `Integer.MAX_VALUE` has lower precedence. You can change your order to something like `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5000` to ensure that the configure bean is fully instantiated before the factory bean is started.

Start with those options and see if they give any indications for the issue. If it still persists, feel free to share with us a reproducible small sample application.

Comment: @sobychako, Added a breakpoint at that line and inspected. The value is not null. But the class has no fields. 
Changed the overridden getOrder config value as suggested, still, the issue persists.
I will create a reproducible sample application quickly and share it here.

Comment: @sobychako, Updated the question with a reproducible sample application.

Comment: Thanks for the sample, this turned out to be a bug in the binder. We will have to make a fix and make it available in the next point release. Any chance you can use the snapshot version of the binder until then?

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. Yes, we can use the SNAPSHOT version for the time being. Please add a comment when the SNAPSHOT version is available. To confirm, it is "spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka" right?

Comment: No, it is `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams`. You will also need a snapshot from `spring-kafka`. I will certainly update here.

Comment: Please update `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams` to `3.2.3-SNAPSHOT` and `spring-kafka` to `2.8.4-SNAPSHOT` respectively in your maven pom. The fix is now part of those snapshots.

Comment: Thanks, @sobychako. I tested it, and it works. However, I noticed that replace-thread takes nearly 40-50 seconds to recover and be ready to consume the following message in a single-thread application. It seems as the whole spring-context gets refreshed each time `StreamThreadExceptionResponse.REPLACE_THREAD` is returned from the **StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler**
Not sure whether you can do anything else to reduce the recovery time further. But, then again, consuming each message starts to throw an exception, it is something else and should be handled in the first place.

Comment: Have you identified what it's doing during that 40-50 seconds? I wonder if it is trying to reload any state store etc. Spring context refresh should not take that long.

Comment: @sobychako, any particular date that spring going to release this fix?

Comment: Hi @bluelabel, the next release train of spring-cloud (`2021.0.2`) is scheduled for 4/19. See here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/milestones. Spring Cloud Stream `3.2.3` will be part of that.